# Cordova - device plugin not working for version 3.2 / 3.3

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I am trying to use device plugin for one of my cordova application running on 3.2 / 3.3.

I have installed devide plugin using CLI and trying to use device's platform uuid methods. but unable to get results using these methods though no error are reported in console.

Any one knows what i am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use lower version, not 3.2/3.3 I think your plugin doesn`t support newest version. Or try to build with Phonegap Build, this service will connect your plugin automatically, you only need to specify name of your plugin, more info you can find in Phonegap Build Docs

Comment: Thanks red_sensor. I tried this plugin on cordova 3.0, but no luck. Do i need to go back to phonegap

Comment: Yes, try it. And try to use version 2.6 or 2.7